# Google news crawler flip pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-crawlers

continuing on previous work to crawl all news result about query and to return title and url, I am refining the crawler to get all results from all pages in Google News. Current code seems can only return the 1st page Googel news search result. Would be grateful to know how to get all pages results. Many thanks!

my codes below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
from random import randint 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


query2Google = input("What do you want from Google News?\n")

def QGN(query2Google):
    s = '"'+query2Google+'"' #Keywords for query
    s = s.replace(" ","+")
    date = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) #timestamp
    filename =query2Google+"_"+date+"_"+'SearchNews.csv' #csv filename
    f = open(filename,"wb")
    url = "http://www.google.com.sg/search?q="+s+"&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:y" # URL for query of news results within one year and sort by date 

    #htmlpage = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    time.sleep(randint(0, 2))#waiting 

    htmlpage = requests.get(url)
    print("Status code: "+ str(htmlpage.status_code))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text,'lxml')

    df = []
    for result_table in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "g"}):
        a_click = result_table.find("a")
        #print ("-----Title----\n" + str(a_click.renderContents()))#Title

        #print ("----URL----\n" + str(a_click.get("href"))) #URL

        #print ("----Brief----\n" + str(result_table.find("div", {"class": "st"}).renderContents()))#Brief

        #print ("Done")
        df=np.append(df,[str(a_click.renderContents()).strip("b'"),str(a_click.get("href")).strip('/url?q='),str(result_table.find("div", {"class": "st"}).renderContents()).strip("b'")])


        df = np.reshape(df,(-1,3))
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Title','URL','Brief'])
    print("Search Crawl Done!")

    df1.to_csv(filename, index=False,encoding='utf-8')
    f.close()
    return

QGN(query2Google)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There used to be an ajax api, but it's no longer avaliable .
Still , you can modify your script with a for loop if you want to get a number of pages , or a while loop if you want to get all pages .
Example :

```
url = "http://www.google.com.sg/search?q="+s+"&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:y&start="  
pages = 10    # the number of pages you want to crawl # 

for next in range(0, pages*10, 10) : 
    page = url + str(next)
    time.sleep(randint(1, 5))    # you may need longer than that #
    htmlpage = requests.get(page)    # you should add User-Agent and Referer #
    print("Status code: " + str(htmlpage.status_code))
    if htmlpage.status_code != 200 : 
        break    # something went wrong #  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text, 'lxml')

    ... process response here ...

    next_page = soup.find('td', { 'class':'b', 'style':'text-align:left' }) 
    if next_page is None or next_page.a is None : 
        break    # there are no more pages #
```

Keep in mind that google doesn't like bots , **you might get a ban .**
You could add 'User-Agent' and 'Referer' in `headers` to simulate a web browser ,   and use `time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 6))` to simulate a human ... or use selenium.

Comment: Hi Adam, the code works perfectly when having multiple pages of result, but I realize the line:
if soup.find('td', { 'class':'b', 'style':'text-align:left' }).a is None : break

will prompt error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a' if the search result is single page and with no page to flip. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: This line checks if there is a next page in the navigation bar, you can see that if you use 'inspect element' in a web browser . If for some reason there is no navigation bar , this line will raise an exception , i will update my code to catch it

Answer (score 0):

You can also add &num=25 to the end of your query and you'll get back a webpage with that number of results. In this example youll get back 25 google results back.